# How to enable to run a GitLab CI pipeline manually outside of cases where they are run automatically?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to have a pipeline that needs to run at each merge request. I would also like to have the ability to run that pipeline manually so that one can anticipate merge issues.

However, if I specify my jobs as

```
only:
  - merge_requests
```

when trying to run the pipeline manually, I am greeted with a

> Pipeline cannot be run. No stages / jobs for this pipeline.

If I use workflows instead,

```
include:
  - template: 'Workflows/MergeRequest-Pipelines.gitlab-ci.yml'
```

I am greeted with a different but equivalent

> Pipeline cannot be run. Pipeline filtered out by workflow rules.

So how can I set up a pipeline that is required for merge requests but that could also be run manually by users on their feature branch?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) instead of [only/except](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic) as the later will be deprecated in the future.

But instead of configuring when every job should run you can use [workflow](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflow) and define for the whole pipeline when it should be created.

In your example the following `workflow` will create a pipeline if it is a merge-request and if the pipeline was manually triggered without a push.

For further reference you can take a look at the possible [values](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) for `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` if you want to change that in the future.

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
```

Comment: Do you mean to say "In your example the following workflow will create a pipeline if it is a merge-request OR if the pipeline was manually triggered without a push."?

Answer (score 4):

Danielnelz's answer is correct. But note that if you're using merge request pipelines, something like this:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS"
      when: never
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_TAG"
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
```

Won't work. You will have to move the `'$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'` line to above the `"$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS"` line. Like this:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS"
      when: never
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_TAG"
```

Why? Because if this condition is true, `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS` (you have an open merge request), gitlab CI won't continue reading the following `if` conditions, so it will never reach the `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"` line. In summary, if you don't make this change you won't be able to run a pipeline from the website having an open MR.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Usually, I'd recommend using the newer rules statement instead of only, that way if you want to run it only manually in merge requests, I'd do something like the following:

[image]

The `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` is a default variable from Gitlab ci should be useful for your use case.